# Best practice SharePoint 2010 with SP1 and IE11, compatibility mode on or off?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility, ie-11

I am using sharepoint 2010 with SP1. We would like to push on all our workstations IE11. But we don't know if we turn for the sharepoint sites compatibility mode on or off. What is the best, on or off for all the end users?

Update: The end users will be used also Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

A good description on the browser support is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx). Basically SP 2010 supports IE 7+ with 32 Bit and limited support on 64 bit.

Also another things is that default SharePoint master page sets the document mode to IE 8 Compatible. So even you upgrade the browser, it will work on IE 8 Compatible document mode.

It can be set with following code.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

We are testing the same thing in our farm as well. we decide to turn on the Enterprise mode(EMIE). there are many things which are not working with IE 11 in native mode.

- datasheet view will not work with IE 11
- trying to edit the page but it fails
- certain webpart properties can not modified.
- Workflow having the issue

I would also recommend you to upgrade your farm to SP2 level, otherwise your issue list will be bigger.

Comment: It is not so easy to upgrade to SP2 because it is a great company and they are afraid for risks. So am I correct you say it is better to turn compatibility mode on for Win7/IE11?

Comment: EMIE(Enterprise Mode), yes you should enable this for better compatibility for older versions of Internet Explorer and tools to manage which Web apps use it

Comment: We were able to get Datasheet View working in IE 11 by installing the [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734). Seems the issue is 64-bit Office as much as IE. For more info, see [You cannot view a list in Datasheet view after you install the 64-bit version of Office 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2266203).

Answer (score 3):

SP2 provided support for IE10. Since you're rolling out IE11, rather than placing the site in Compatibility View, try IE11's Enterprise Mode: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx