# Unable to open the edit webpart menu after webpart first creation and show the webpart's properties toolpanel

Tags: web-part, publishing-site, accessibility

The sharepoint admin team had activated the publishing features for me in order to have the content query webpart available. Since then I have been  trying to add the content query webpart and any other webpart  with a lot of difficulty.

First, I couldn't update the existing webpart of my page because the edit webpart menu couldn't showing, Those webpart was webpart added before the feature got activated.

Then I decided to delete all webparts on one page, thinking that it will solve the problem, but I am able to add the webpart and have the edit webpart menu show, see the webpart's properties toolpanel  but with different appearance ( as if there is  a javascript or browser accessibility issue on some property webpart's properties toolpanel  ), **then I was able to add any webpart, show the edit webpart menu and update the webpart using the webpart's properties toolpanel , but if I close and save my webpart I am unable to reopen the edit webpart menu the next time after the webpart have been created, therefore unable to open the webpart's properties toolpanel**.

Any help on how to solve this. I am using Internet explorer 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using IE11, you will encounter these types of difficulties.
You can open the site in compatibility mode in IE11, or use a different browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc) and it should work fine.  We experienced this same issue when testing IE11 deployments in our organization, and ended up having to update everyone's settings to add our Intranet SharePoint site to the Compatibility list in IE11.

Comment: Thanks Kolten , I am going to explore those option, and see if   adding the Intranet SharePoint site to the Compatibility list in IE11 will solve that and I will update.

Comment: That was the issue I reverted to IE9 and everything works just fine. thanks for the help. I got this link which explain it well http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/sharepoint-2010-issues-with-internet-explorer-11/4831aa12-9d29-4a0a-ac9d-80fb8a20dc46?auth=1

Comment: Excellent - can you mark this as the answer to your question please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SharePoint 2010 has some issues with IE 11, and in your case, web part properties cannot be modified and you get a weird looking web part property menu. To get around this, you'll need to run your site in compatibility mode. Here are some articles that have more info abut SharePoint 2010 and IE 11 problems and compatibility mode:

- [SharePoint and Internet Explorer](http://corypeters.net/2013/10/sharepoint-and-internet-explorer-11/)
- [Best practice SharePoint 2010 with SP1 and IE11, compatibility mode on or off?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112499/best-practice-sharepoint-2010-with-sp1-and-ie11-compatibility-mode-on-or-off)
- [Using IE 11? We Need a Patch!](http://appdevonsharepoint.com/using-ie-11-we-need-a-patch/)